# Vue set the computed property to the empty if the value assign is empty

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In this code below I have tried to set the property for the computed field. Since I want to also be able to assign values to the computed property, I define a set function in the SelectedType computed.

But when the computed property is set to the empty array. The computed property set the previous data it doesn't get updated.

Like when i do `this.SelectedType = reduced` in `updateSubscription` methods in first `uid` type the value are good as it is present in the `selectedPaymentType` but incase of `uid==2` the `SelectedType` should be null. But it is getting the previously selected values.

How to set the `SelectedType`  as empty when the array returned is empty? What should be the workaround in this case?

I am stuck now.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',

    selectedPaymentType: [{
      uid: 1,
      PayTypeId: 1,
      Remarks: "sell"
    }, {
      uid: 1,
      PayTypeId: 2,
      Remarks: "buy"
    }, {
      uid: 1,
      PayTypeId: 3,
      Remarks: "thing"
    }],
    PaymentType: [{
        Id: 1,
        Text: "Cash"
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        Text: "Check"
      },
      {
        Id: 3,
        Text: "Paypal"
      }
    ],
    selectePayTypeIds: {},
    typedRemarks: {}
  },
  created: function() {
  },
  methods: {
    updateSubscription: function(e) {

      let userId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-userId');

      var reduced = []
      this.selectedPaymentType.forEach(function(option) {
        if (option.uid == userId) {
          var someNewValue = {
            PayTypeId: option.PayTypeId,
            Remarks: option.Remarks
          }
          reduced.push(someNewValue);
        }
      });
      this.SelectedType = reduced;
      var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal'), {
        keyboard: false
      })

      myModal.show()

    },

  },
  computed: {
    SelectedType: {
      get: function() {
        var vm = this;
        return Object.keys(vm.selectePayTypeIds).filter(function(selectedPayTypeId) {
          return vm.selectePayTypeIds[selectedPayTypeId];
        }).map(function(selectedPayTypeId) {
          return {
            PayTypeId: selectedPayTypeId,
            Remarks: vm.typedRemarks[selectedPayTypeId] || ''
          }
        });
      },
      set: function(newSelectedType) {
        var vm = this;
        newSelectedType.forEach(function(sType) {
          Vue.set(vm.selectePayTypeIds, sType.PayTypeId, true);
          Vue.set(vm.typedRemarks, sType.PayTypeId, sType.Remarks);
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Subscribe User</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td><a v-on:click="updateSubscription" data-userId='1' class="btn btn-link">Update Subscription</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td><a v-on:click="updateSubscription" data-userId='2' class="btn btn-link">Update Subscription</a></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p> SelectedType {{ SelectedType }}</p>
          <div v-for="(pay, index) in PaymentType">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectePayTypeIds[pay.Id]" />
            {{pay.Text}}
            <input type="input" v-model="typedRemarks[pay.Id]">
            <!-- What goes here on :value attributes? -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```